# recursive function in helper js throws error

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have the following code and im trying to delete all empty child nodes. but the call to "removeEmptyChildNodes" is throwing  the following error

> Uncaught Error in $A.getCallback() [removeEmptyChildNodes is not
> defined] Callback failed: apex://GanttData/ACTION$getData Callback
> failed: apex://GanttData/ACTION$getData

can someone please help? below is my helper code

```
({
    getData : function (cmp) {
        var action = cmp.get("c.getData");
        action.setParams({
            recordid: cmp.get('v.recordId')
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                var data = response.getReturnValue();
                var temojson = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).split('items').join('_children'));
                console.log(temojson);
                removeEmptyChildNodes(JSON.parse(temojson));
                console.log(temojson);
                cmp.set('v.gridData', JSON.parse(temojson));
                cmp.set('v.loading', false);
            }
            // error handling when state is "INCOMPLETE" or "ERROR"
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    removeEmptyChildNodes : function (app){
      app.forEach(function(d){
        if(d._children.length == 0){
          delete d._children;
          //console.log('_children:', d);
        }else if(d._children.length > 0){
            removeEmptyChildNodes(d._children)
        }
      });
    }
})
```

Comment: Have you tried `this.removeEmptyChildNodes(JSON.parse(temojson));`?

Comment: The error claims that removeEmptyChildNodes  is not defined; therefore try moving its definition above the getData definition

Comment: tried both the above, same error.

Comment: Using browser development tools call the function manually from the console to check if it is defined or not.

Answer (score 1):

If the above code shown is inside `controller` then write this.

```
const a = component.get('c.removeEmptyChildNodes');
$A.enqueueAction(a);
```

Or else if the above code is from helper then do this, but make sure helper is also passed as parameter in `getData(cmp, event, helper)` from controller:

```
helper.removeEmptyChildNodes(JSON.parse(temojson));
```

`this` might not work because `setCallback` has a function, so using `this` might limit the scope to that function.

Comment: my function "removeEmptyChildNodes " is in the helper. using your code did not work, same error.

Comment: Please edit your question and update your code above, and it should work, if its not working then you might have done something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is when you call removeEmptyChildNodes the argument your are passing is getting undefined for some reason.
You can try something like this to execute your recursive function.

```
 return this.removeEmptyChildNodes(d._children);
```

Comment: FYI. code becomes ~100 times slower if you are using delete in loops.